# collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath doesn't works

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uicollectionview

this is my code, which doesn't works

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    InfoViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"infoID"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

is it required to use this method too?

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

anyway, this doesn't helps

Comment: did you set this class as the collection view delegate?

Comment: yep, i did set delegates

Comment: did you put a breakpoint to test if it's called? how did you set the delegate?

Comment: i have fixed. problem was with navigation controller